# The Monitor executable launcher was unable to locate its companion shared library - when trying to open monitor in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

> The Monitor executable launcher was unable to locate its companion shared library

is the error I get when I try to open the DDMS monitor (via the little Droid icon next to the SDK manager icon) in Android Studio.

This was working fine before Christmas, all that's happened is that I've updated various SDK bits via the SDK manager.

There **are** many similar questions, but all relate to **Eclipse** and the answers are **not obviously applicable** to my problem, which is in **Android Studio**. Most solutions involve solving issues stemming from unzipping Eclipse, but Android Studio just installs from an executable (which I've tried re-downloading and installing to no avail).

If I try to open another project I get 'Android Device Monitor is already launched'.

I'm really not sure what causes the problem, so I'm not sure what code to include. So here's my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion '21.0.1'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "XXXXXXX.XXXXXXX.XXXXXXX.XXXXXXX.XXXXXXX"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.1.11'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:21.0.0+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.+'
    compile files('libs/comscore.jar')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By heading to - C:\Users\administrator\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools (or your equivalent) I've managed to get the DDMS open by opening *ddms.bat*.

It still doesn't work from Android Studio as it seems to be missing some connection there, but at least I can continue working.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on MacOS 10.12.5 - reinstalling did not help. I then figured out that the root cause was the JDK version.  Installing a current JDK 8 (installing JRE 8 is not enough!) solved it.

You can check if this is the cause by executing bin/archquery

If you don't have the right SDK you will see:

```
imac:tools$ bin/archquery
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/archquery/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

after installing JDK8 you should get:

```
imac:tools$ bin/archquery
x86_64
```